# Getting notification after countdown timer in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm building an app in Android Studio for countdown timer from 40 min, I want to  get notification after the time is complete, the problem is where should I put  the codes for notification for it to appear after the countdown is complete.
this is what I have trying and it clashes after the countdown
public void startTimer() {

```
    CountDownTimer cdt= new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timeLeft = millisUntilFinished;
            updateTimer();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            NewMessageNotification sms = new NewMessageNotification();
            sms.notify();

        }
    };
    cdt.start();
    startBtn.setText("PAUSE");
    timeRunning = true;
}
```

Comment: Hi Magige, Please provide more information on what you already tried, add code snippets and ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

The `CountDownTimer` class has two callbacks: `onTick(long millisUntilFinished)` and `onFinish()`. The first is fired on regular intervals while the second is fired when the time is up.

So if you want the notification to be shown when time is up, your code should be added inside the `onFinish()` exactly where you override it.

Example:

```java
CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     @override
     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         //code for regular intervals or nothing 
     }

     @override
     public void onFinish() {
         //your code for notification
     }
  };

  cdt.start();
```

And it's done